# Show pandas Dataframe in webpage and dynamically filter using Dash

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to display a data frame with Dash. The data frame that I have is https://www.kaggle.com/timoboz/superbowl-history-1967-2020. My goal is to show the data frame on the webpage with one search button that dynamically searches all the columns and filters the data frame.

So far, I have the following code that displays the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
df  = pd.read_csv('./Data/superbowl.csv')
PAGE_SIZE = 10
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='datatable-paging',
    columns=[
        {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns #sorted(df.columns)
    ],
    page_current=0,
    page_size=PAGE_SIZE,
    page_action='custom',

    sort_action='custom',
    sort_mode='single',
    sort_by=[]
)


@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-paging', 'data'),
    [Input('datatable-paging', "page_current"),
     Input('datatable-paging', "page_size"),
     Input('datatable-paging', 'sort_by')])
def update_table(page_current,page_size,sort_by):
    if len(sort_by):
        dff = df.sort_values(
            sort_by[0]['column_id'],
            ascending=sort_by[0]['direction'] == 'asc',
            inplace=False
        )
    else:
        # No sort is applied
        dff = df

    return dff.iloc[
           page_current * page_size:(page_current + 1) * page_size
           ].to_dict('records')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: Output so far]
After reading through the documentation https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/callbacks especially 'Backend Paging with Filtering', I couldn't find a way to have like a single textbox that would search all the columns and filter the data frame for the matched entries.

Comment: Try adding `filter_action='native'` as an argument within `dash_table.DataTable`

Comment: @sumshyftw that adds filtering per column. I am trying to consolidate all the filter to one textbox/input box which filters across all the columns.

Comment: filter_action native is not server side sorting AFAIK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use an input component for your search query. This can then update the table by doing a pandas filter. This returns all the rows where any cell contains the text.

Example filter callback below:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable', 'data'),
    [Input('filter-input', 'value')])
def update_table(filter_string):
    dff = df[df.apply(lambda row: row.str.contains(filter_string, regex=False).any(), axis=1)]
    return dff.to_dict('records')
```

Your input component below (note the use of debounce - this means that the callback will only be actioned when the user presses enter):

With `import dash_core_components as dcc`

```
dcc.Input(value='', id='filter-input', placeholder='Filter', debounce=True)
```

Taking your current code and putting this all together:

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

df = pd.read_csv('./Data/superbowl.csv')
PAGE_SIZE = 10
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(value='', id='filter-input', placeholder='Filter', debounce=True),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-paging',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns  # sorted(df.columns)
        ],
        page_current=0,
        page_size=PAGE_SIZE,
        page_action='custom',

        sort_action='custom',
        sort_mode='single',
        sort_by=[]
    )
])


@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-paging', 'data'),
    [Input('datatable-paging', 'page_current'),
     Input('datatable-paging', 'page_size'),
     Input('datatable-paging', 'sort_by'),
     Input('filter-input', 'value')])
def update_table(page_current, page_size, sort_by, filter_string):
    # Filter
    dff = df[df.apply(lambda row: row.str.contains(filter_string, regex=False).any(), axis=1)]
    # Sort if necessary
    if len(sort_by):
        dff = dff.sort_values(
            sort_by[0]['column_id'],
            ascending=sort_by[0]['direction'] == 'asc',
            inplace=False
        )

    return dff.iloc[
           page_current * page_size:(page_current + 1) * page_size
           ].to_dict('records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Hope this helps,

Ollie